# Django same project multiple times on one server

Tags: python, django, apache

I had to develop something in Django (new to it) and it went quite smoothly. But after delivering to the client I had to setup a second "testing" instance so that any new features would be tested on it to avoid errors in the production one.
And I have only one apache server at my disposal and this breed some weird things.

I run my applications by adding path to the wsgi script in the httpd.conf.
It works fine, the new server is up and running. it used a different database so all is good. But it doesent use the views and models from its folder, it used the ones from the original app instead and I just ran out of ideas on how to fix it. Please help me in some way.

Comment: What does your configuration file look like? What does the `settings.py` file look like from your django app?

Comment: It looks exactly the same in both with some differences. They use different databases and in things like this `ROOT_URLCONF = 'Ster2.urls'` I use "Ster" and "Ster2" so it differs.

Comment: Are there any places where you're using an absolute path in `settings.py` that refers to the original app, when it should refer to the new app?

Comment: No, I never use an absolute path

Comment: To clarify: is the code you delivered to the client running on a different machine to the one you're using for development?

Comment: Both are on the same server/machine

Comment: Well, if possible, do the development on a different machine to avoid all the rename hackery. As for the more immediate problem, I can only assume that you haven't replaced all instances of `Ster` with `Ster2` in your scripts.

Comment: Do You have any idea where should I change it besides settings and wsgi.py  ? Because there it is all done And I just think I will create a new project and copy the models and views to just have it done without any trouble

Comment: Well, presumably your `urls.py` has something like `from Ster.views import something`, so you'd need to change that too, but it'll be easier to create a new copy of the directory tree, and use the same names. You probably ought to look into using version control as well.

Comment: Ok this is now a little strange. I created a comlpetly new project and this happened again. I think the only possibility that this happens is that the app is named the same in both, I managed to think of a way to make it work even if it did so but I will just run the test project on a different server to avoid this complication.

Comment: @shym If you're using the same app name, you'll also need to check that your `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` is pointing to the correct codebase for each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your two django projects should be deployed on your staging and production server as two completely seperate projects/directories.

If you use version control, this could be as trivial as branching your main project and adding the new features.  After you have two seperate code bases you can put your fixed branch on your production server.

Your project can exist anywhere on your server.  You could set up a staging subdomain and create a virtualhost that points to your django project branch
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html
This would allow both projects to exist on the same server, without one project having to be aware of the other